# Remove array with single element from assosiative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 96
            [1] => ML based
            [7] => Open
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => Application 
            [7] => Open
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 98
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 99
        )

)
```

I want to remove

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 98
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 99
        )

)
```

from this array

I tried:

```
$data = array_map('array_filter', $rowData);
unset($data[0][0]);
```

**Expected output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 96
        [1] => ML based )
        [7] => Open
    )

)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 97
        [1] => Application 
        [7] => Open
    )

)
```

any help would be Appreciated .

Comment: So you want the array with single element to be removed, right?

Comment: @SougataBose yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will work. Try -

```
array_filter($array, function ($a) {
    return count($a[0]) == 3; // return array with 3 elements only
});
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/1051265)

Comment: thanks dear but i got an error like too many nested blocks in function declaration.I am using MVC